# Manual Transaction in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to use Codeigniter transactions and as I am new to it, I really don't know to use `$this->db->trans_begin()` or $`this->db->trans_start().`

What are manual transactions and when should we consider it to be used.

And once the transaction is committed, should `$this->db->trans_off()` be used every time to continue auto-commit?

Comment: Have you searched yourself for the answer? Perhaps read this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: I have read that. But when is it that $this->db->trans_begin() has to be used? If $this->db->trans_start() is used, then are rollback possible too?

Answer (score 3):

1. `$this->db->trans_start()`  and `$this->db->trans_complete();` used together.

If Any query between those two statement fail it will do rollback them automatically.If success it will commit them automatically.

2. But if you use `$this->db->trans_begin();` any query after this line nothing will happen until you commit them or rollback them.

**See Examples([from CI docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html))**

1. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions
2. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually

`$this->db->trans_off();` means you can disable transaction.Its up-to you whether you off it or not. I never use it, that means I always turn on transaction.[see details](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#enabling-transactions)

Comment: but where should we use manual transaction & where should we use automatic?

Comment: If you have a bunch of queries and each of the queries doesn't make sense without the others, i.e. if only one of them fails, you don't want to execute any of the other queries, use trans_begin. If you just want to rollback those who fail, i.e. others still should be executed, use trans_start.